# Can a macro redefinition be applied to single cpp file?

Tags: c++, macros, rapidjson

I'm using rapidjson, which is an all header library. In `rapidjson.h`, there is a macro `RAPIDJSON_ASSERT`, in one of my cpp files, I would like to redefine it, so I have this code at the top of my file:

```
#include "stdafx.h" // for windows
#pragma push_macro("RAPIDJSON_ASSERT")
#define RAPIDJSON_ASSERT(x) if(!(x)) throw std::logic_error("rapidjson exception");

#include "rapidjson/rapidjson.h"
#include "rapidjson/document.h"
#include "rapidjson/stringbuffer.h"
#include "rapidjson/writer.h"

....
....
#pragma pop_macro("RAPIDJSON_ASSERT")
```

Here is the whay that `rapidjson.h` defines `RAPIDJSON_ASSERT`:

```
#ifndef RAPIDJSON_ASSERT
#include <cassert>
#define RAPIDJSON_ASSERT(x) assert(x)
#endif // RAPIDJSON_ASSERT
```

The documentation states that to override the `RAPIDJSON_ASSERT` logic, you just have to define `RAPIDJSON_ASSERT` before you include any of the files.

The issue is that when I run the code in the debugger, `RAPIDJSON_ASSERT` is not being redefined. I checked `stdafx.h` for anything which would include the rapidjson header files, and there isn't anything.

I was under the assumption that each compilation unit should run through the header files.

Note that if I move the redefinition of the macro into `stdafx.h` I get the macro redefined, but I was hoping to be able to do it per compilation unit.

Comment: do you include rapidjson in stdafx.h?

Comment: The pattern seems wrong. Did you want to change the macro inside of rapidjson for this translation unit, or simply inside your translation unit? If the latter, put the redefine after the rapidjson headers. Otherwise, rapidjson might simply redefine the macro itself

Comment: @jaggedSpire - I did not include rapidjson.h in stdafx.h, so I'm not sure why it won't override the macro.

Comment: @KABoissonneault - I added some info to the question. Specifically about how rapidjson.h does the define. It appears that you are supposed to define the macro before including it, not after.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to change the definition of RAPIDJSON_ASSERT for the rapidjson code itself

If so, you need to add a #define after the place where it is defined. Unless you want to edit the rapidjson.h file, the only alternative is to do this:

```
#include "stdafx.h" // for windows

// One would assume that the macro gets defined somewhere inside here
#include "rapidjson/rapidjson.h"

// Compiler will complain about macro redefinition without this #undef
#undef RAPIDJSON_ASSERT    
#define RAPIDJSON_ASSERT(x) if(!(x)) throw std::logic_error("rapidjson exception");

#include "rapidjson/document.h"
#include "rapidjson/stringbuffer.h"
#include "rapidjson/writer.h"
```

Now the definition of RAPIDJSON_ASSERT is changed for the rest of the header files. You don't need the push_macro and pop_macro shenanigans - macros only are valid for each unit

Note that it's not a a good thing to redefine things for libraries using #define

Comment: I added some info into the question, but the docs specify that you should define RAPIDJSON_ASSERT before including the file, not after. What doesn't make sense, is that it appears that the #ifndef statement rapidjson.h is somehow being checked only once across all compilation units.

Comment: Turn off precompiled headers completely and try?

Comment: I was thinking that precompiled headers might be the issue. I'll give that a try.